# Could we create a vehicle mod and add it to the already installed game?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am trying to get hands-on the UE4 modding. The tutorials I followed contains examples to modify the level and load that level. ex: [Add mod-support to your Unreal Engine 4 Game](https://www.tomlooman.com/add-mod-support-to-your-unreal-engine-4-game/)

What I need to do is create my own vehicle and add it to the existing installed game's mod folder so that vehicle is loaded to the existing terrains which were received by default with the game

It would be very helpful if you have some insight regarding my problem and at least if have some links or tutorials, please mention

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I finally found what I searched for from this
[Modding](https://infernium.fandom.com/wiki/Modding) tutorial series

This series simply explains how to inject your content to a created game and how it is applied to the main game

Thank you